# smartctl -t long, halts before completion

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I'm hoping this is the right spot to ask a question like this.

Does this indicate that I have an issue with this drive? It's somewhat new, and within the return window. I ran `smartctl -t long /dev/sdb` and waited overnight. Today I see this when I run `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`:

```
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  37) The self-test routine was interrupted
                    by the host with a hard or soft reset.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  101) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (1633) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   135   135   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       100
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   082   082   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       335 (Average 381)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   133   133   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       846
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
 22 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       98
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       98
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   062   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 17/67)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      50%       832         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       753         -
# 3  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      10%       660         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       610         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       233         -
# 6  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       215         -
# 7  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       214         -
# 8  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       212         -
# 9  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       211         -
#10  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       210         -
#11  Selective offline   Aborted by host               10%       210         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       189         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       174         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       162         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       157         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       155         -
#17  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       145         -
#18  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       145         -
#19  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       143         -
#20  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       142         -
#21  Selective offline   Completed without error       00%       141         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN      MIN_LBA      MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1  17186633728  17289361408  Not_testing
    2  20213526528  20316254208  Not_testing
    3  23240419328  23343147008  Not_testing
    4  26267312128  26370039808  Not_testing
    5            0            0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

`dmesg` shows this (related to this drive):

```
[34073.795675] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x4000 SErr 0x840000 action 0x6 frozen
[34073.795680] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[34073.795681] ata6: SError: { CommWake LinkSeq }
[34073.795684] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[34073.795685] ata6.00: cmd 60/58:70:b8:11:93/00:00:07:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 45056 in
                        res 40/00:00:b0:10:93/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[34073.795688] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[34073.795691] ata6: hard resetting link
[34074.113795] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[34074.134975] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[34074.137875] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[34074.137883] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[34074.137884] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[34074.137886] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 07 93 11 b8 00 00 00 58 00 00
[34074.137887] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 127078840 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[34074.137893] zio pool=nas vdev=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_<drive serial number>-part1 error=5 type=1 offset=65063317504 size=45056 flags=180980
[34074.137898] ata6: EH complete
[34325.178736] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x4000000 SErr 0x840000 action 0x6 frozen
[34325.178749] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[34325.178750] ata6: SError: { CommWake LinkSeq }
[34325.178753] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[34325.178754] ata6.00: cmd 60/58:d0:38:20:b5/00:00:c5:05:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 45056 in
                        res 40/00:00:08:71:bc/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[34325.178758] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[34325.178760] ata6: hard resetting link
[34325.493107] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[34325.548049] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[34325.551125] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[34325.551132] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#26 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[34325.551137] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#26 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[34325.551138] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#26 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 05 c5 b5 20 38 00 00 00 58 00 00
[34325.551139] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24791818296 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[34325.551144] zio pool=nas vdev=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_<drive serial number>-part1 error=5 type=1 offset=12693409918976 size=45056 flags=180980
```

I can re-run the smart scan, but this took almost a whole day, so if this indicates something is wrong, I'd rather just deal with it upfront. Thanks!

Comment: Next time include drive model please (don't cut from report).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
> tag#14 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command

Sense Keys are messages generated by the storage target.
These messages indicate that the server successfully submitted the
IO request to the target, but the target rejected the IO request with
an error message.

There can be many reasons for such errors. In Github bug report
[the return of "Unaligned write command" errors #10094](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10094), the reasons went from bad disk, to bad cable,
or incompatible motherboard, or even a bad motherboard.

My advice is not to think twice : The new disk is having problems or
is incompatible, so the easiest solution would be to return it.
If another disk of a different manufacturer will show similar errors,
you should rather check your hardware for problems.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. And I agree with the "if it's bad, return and retry." It'll be way easier now that in the future with data on it. (I didn't realize reputation wouldn't transfer from Stack Overflow, so I can't vote up your response yet.)